# Eager loading the first record of a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to tune my site to be faster but am having issues tuning an association.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :photos, as: :annotatable
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :annotatable, polymorphic:true
end
```

I only want to eager load the first photo for each post but am running into syntax errors due to it being polymorphic.

Here is what I have tried:

```
  has_many :primary_photo, as: :annotable, -> { order('photos.sort_order ASC').limit(1) }, class_name: 'Photo'
```

The error I get when I try the above is:

`syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...r('sort_order ASC').limit(1) }, class_name: 'Photo' ... ^`

And then: `Post.includes(:primary_photo)`

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: What error message are you getting?  You probably want to add `.limit(1)` to your lambda.

Comment: @Daiku - Updated with the error I get and your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature expects the options to go after the scope. Try it like this:

```
has_many :primary_photo, -> { order('photos.sort_order ASC').limit(1) }, class_name: 'Photo', as: :annotable
```